# limiting keyboard inputs

Tags: javascript, keyboard, barcode-scanner

I have a code and I need is to limit the keyboard input into 1 character in the textarea

while having the barcode scanner wtih 1 scan all the barcode characters into the textarea

```
  function snip(len) {
  return function (e) {e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, len);};
  }
  function prevent(len) {
  return function () {
    if (e.target.value.length >= len) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
  }
  }

  var len = 13;

  var textarea = document.getElementById('texta'),
  sn = snip(len),
  p1 = prevent(len), p2 = snip(len - 12);

  textarea.addEventListener('change', p2, true);
  textarea.addEventListener('input', p1, true);
  textarea.addEventListener('keydown', p1, true);
  textarea.addEventListener('keypress', p1, true);
  textarea.addEventListener('keyup', p1, true);
  textarea.addEventListener('paste', sn, true);
```

any idea on how to seperate code them especially the keyboard
please help me
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your problem, but wouldn't maxlength do the trick?

```
<textarea maxlength="13">
```